# expected string or byte-like object NLTK Mysql

Tags: python, sql, nltk

can you help me with this error?

```py
def get_db():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="cosmos"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql_select="SELECT article FROM crawling_sm"
    mycursor.execute(sql_select)
    data=mycursor.fetchall()
    for z in range(len(data)):
        text_sents=sent_tokenize(data[z])

def process_text(text_article):
    text_sents=text_article
    text_sents_clean = [remove_string_special_characters(s) for s in text_sents] #if s.istitle() == False]
    doc_info = get_doc(text_sents_clean)
    #freqDict_list = create_freq_dict(text_sents_clean)
    #TF_scores = computeTF(doc_info, freqDict_list)
    print(text_sents)

    get_db()
```

the error message is the article that I selected from a database cannot be split into some text, I trying to use sent_tokenize but there's some error message expected a string or bytes-like object

the error message:

> File "C:\Users\HP Laptop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1295, in _slices_from_text
>       for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I already put the error message @AkshayNevrekar

Comment: That is short error message. Please provide complete error traceback from your console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
data = mycursor.fetchall()
```

returns a list of *tuples*, even if the query is returning a single column.

So rather than returning something like

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

it returns

```
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('f',)]
```

The solution is to pass the first element of each tuple to the `sent_tokenize` function.

```
for row in data:
    text_sents = sent_tokenize(row[0])
```